# Preferred way to fix "comparison between signed and unsigned integer" warnings?

Tags: c, integer, unsigned, signed

What is assumed to be the preferred way to fix "comparison between signed and unsigned integer" warnings safely? In my case I have to compare some uint_32 variables with #define constants.

Really simplified:

```
#define MAX(A,B) ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a < __b ? __b : __a; })
#define c (10)
unsigned int d = 11;
if(MAX(c,d)>10){
  //...
}
```

But I have *really* a lot of such cases - what would you suggest to solve this?

Comment: Does this specific example really give a warning? I already considered this warning annoying, but if it can't tell that the signed operand is a positive constant and thus unchanged by the promotion to unsigned, all I can say is that you should file a bug report with the gcc team and turn off the warning. Cerainly don't clutter your code to work around this...

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure it would go away if you just replaced the ugly `MAX` macro full of gcc extensions with the standard version. Nobody expects a `MIN` or `MAX` macro not to evaluate its arguments more than once. If nothing else, rename `__a` and `__b` to legal variable names. Double-underscore-prefixed names are reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you can just change your constant to be unsigned as well:

```
#define c 10U
```

or alternatively, use a cast so that the `typeof` in your macro creates an `unsigned` variable:

```
if (MAX((unsigned)c, d) > 10) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if is totally correct but my logic says this:
If an `int` (signed) is < 0, this value is lesser than the unsigned one.
Otherwise, you can just cast it to an unsigned int

So what about this:

```
#define INT_MAX_UINT(value1,value2) (value1<0?value2:(((uint)value1)>value2?value1:value2))
```

This is the best idea, however you cannot make it "generic", I mean you have to build a `UINT_MAX_INT` if you want reverse the params order

If you are using Visual Studio and you simply don't want to hear the warning (because you are sure it will not give any problem):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Good luck

Comment: You can make it generic with more gcc extensions. It's easy to test which arguments are unsigned with `#define IS_UNSIGNED(A) ((__typeof(A)__)-1 > 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

My simple suggestion would be to use what you know about the signed and unsigned int types.

Maybe you might try:

```
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int max(int six, unsigned int uix) {
   if (uix > INT_MAX || six < 0) { return uix; }
   return ((unsigned int) six >= uix) ? (unsigned int) six : uix;
}
```

note the "type contagion" (i can't think of a better word to describe it as the effect is implicit)

you might even be able to inline this function.

Comment: It should be called a strange name like 'max_si_ui', however, to avoid somebody mistaking it for normal 'max' and calling it with a negative int as the second parameter. Otherwise this is a fine solution to the mixed compare issue in general - but I'm not sure it helps in the present case.

Answer (score -1):

I use C++ promotions that are "value-preserving". The question is how to find with operand need to be promoted.Compare between signed unsigned is equivalent to unsigned compare after check that signed number is positive.
If both number has the same size i cast to unsigned else I cast to the biggest one.
The next template implementation of less equal works fine for me.

```
/*
 * Signed unsigned safe less equal function implementation
 * 
 * a <=b
 * int uint --> (a <= 0) || ( b >= (B)a  && a <= (A)b )
 * uint int --> (b >= 0) && ( a <= (A)b  && b >= (B)a )
 *
 * all comparations are done using positive numbers
 * If integral promotion is used then one condition can be remove
 *
 *  a <= b
 * int  uint --> (a <=0) ||  [ (uint)a <= b | a <= (int)b ]
 * uint int  --> (b >=0) ||  [ (uint)a <= b | a <= (int)b ]
 *
 * The question is. cast to B or to A?
 *
 *  size A = size B
 *  uint <= int  A
 *  int  <= uint B
 *
 *  size A > size B
 *  uint <= int  A
 *  int  <= uint A
 *
 *  size A < size B
 *  uint <= int B
 *  int <= uint B
 */
namespace Range
{
    /*
     * if sizeof A > sizeof B then casting to A
     * if sizeof A < sizeof B then casting to B
     * if sizeof A == sizeof A then
     *  if A is signed cast to B else cast to A
     *
     * true means static cast to A
     */
    template<size_t a,size_t b,bool intA>
    struct _le_cast_to_a_
    {
        constexpr static const bool value = (a > b) ? true : (a < b) ? false : intA ? false : true;
    };

    // Casting to A default implementation
    template<bool cast_to_a = true>
    struct _less_equal
    {
        template <class A,class B>
        static inline bool le(A a,B b)
        {
            return (a <= static_cast<A>(b));
        }
    };
    // Casting to b specialization
    template<>
    struct _less_equal<false>
    {
        template <class A,class B>
        static inline bool le(A a,B b)
        {
            return (static_cast<B>(a) <= b);
        }
    };
    /*
     * Parameter
     * is A int, is B int
     */
    template<bool intA,bool intB>
    struct _impl1_
    {
        template<class A,class B>
        static inline bool less_equal(A a,B b)
        {
            return a <= b;
        }
    };
    // Specialization for uint int
    template<>
    struct _impl1_<false,true>
    {
        template<class A,class B>
        static inline bool less_equal(A a,B b)
        {
            return (b >=0) && _less_equal< _le_cast_to_a_<sizeof(A),sizeof(B),std::is_signed<A>::value >::value >::le(a,b);
        }
    };
    // Specialization for int uint
    template<>
    struct _impl1_<true,false>
    {
        template<class A,class B>
        static inline bool less_equal(A a,B b)
        {
            return (a <=0) || _less_equal< _le_cast_to_a_<sizeof(A),sizeof(B),std::is_signed<A>::value >::value >::le(a,b);
        }
    };

    template<class A, class B>
    static bool less_equal(A a, B b)
    {
        return _impl1_<std::is_signed<A>::value,std::is_signed<B>::value>::less_equal(a, b);
    }

    template<class V, class T>
    static bool check(V v, T start, T end)
    {
        return less_equal(start, v) && less_equal(v, end);
    }

    void test()
    {
        volatile char c = 7;
        volatile unsigned char uc = 0xAA;
        volatile int i = -1;
        volatile unsigned int ui = 0xF000;
        volatile bool b;

        b = less_equal(c, uc);
        b = less_equal(uc, c);

        b = less_equal(c, i);
        b = less_equal(i, c);

        b = less_equal(ui, uc);
        b = less_equal(uc, ui);

        b = less_equal(i, uc);
        b = less_equal(uc, i);
        b = less_equal(ui, c);

        b = less_equal(c, ui);
        b= (c <=0) || (static_cast<unsigned int>(c) <= ui);
        b= (c <=0) || (c <= static_cast<char>(ui));
    }
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. This question is about C!